# How to count ad banner impressions on Android?

Tags: android, admob, banner

Admob banners can be used with this [AdListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/banner):

```
public abstract class AdListener {
    public void onAdLoaded();
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode);
    public void onAdOpened();
    public void onAdClosed();
    public void onAdLeftApplication();
}
```

`onAdOpened()` means

> ad opens an overlay that covers the screen

and is called when the user *clicks* on ad.
But how can I count the number of *impressions*?

(For example, a banner showing for 4 minutes at refresh rate of 30 seconds would produce 8 impressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An impression simply says that the ad is present so the onAdLoaded is where you would want to place your impression tracking.